# What are the $^ and $$ varables in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

The [Windows PowerShell Language Specification Version 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36389) says, that

> The variables $$ and $^ are reserved for use in an interactive environment, which is outside the scope of this specification.

but I can't find any information on google.
What are they for ?
Where do I find information ?

Comment: @vonPryz was faster than me :D Found the same info here: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_variables.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [automatic variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347675.aspx). As per the documentation,

```
$$
   Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.
$^
   Contains the first token in the last line received by the session.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can't see much use for them. Seems impossible to find `"$$" site:technet.microsoft.com` on Googe

Comment: @fbehrens When googling, you might have better luck using character names instead of raw special characters. That is, `dollar` instead of `$` and `caret` instead of `^`.

Comment: You can also find the information within PowerShell's help files: `Get-Help About_Automatic_Variables`